# How to disable windows 10 gestures (using wacom tablet as a touchpad)?

Tags: windows, touchpad, gestures

My mouse stopped working so in the meanwhile I'm using my wacom intuos as a touchpad, it used to be Ok but now the windows gestures are making it impossible to work.

Every time I'm on the desktop or a window focus out because I opened the start menu (windows explorer), I can't move my mouse from left to right without triggering the new virtual desktop manager on windows, there are other annoying gestures but that one is making working hell at the moment.

Every time I search for ways to disable gestures, they all say to check the touchpad option in the mouse properties, but my windows doesn't have any option for the touchpad since its a desktop machine, even the search doesn't return anything when searching touchpad or trackpad.

I'm literally stuck with those damn obnoxious gestures.

Answer (score 1):

You can control this specific behavior in Wacom Desktop Center. See the option "Edge Swipes" in this screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Because we use wacom tablet as a touchpad, so the touchpad on wacom tablet is equivalent to a mouse with gesture, the wacom tablet supports gesture. So we can not find  touchpad option in the mouse properties, we need to go to wacom's official website to download a corresponding driver and install this driver in our desktop. Then we find an interface like this to disable gestures.

[image]